# PyQt5 - TypeError: signal has 0 argument(s) but 1 provided

Tags: python, stdout, pyqt5, signals-slots, qtextedit

I am trying to redirect "sys.stdout" to `QTextEdit`, here is my code:

```
class Communicate(QObject):  
    printText = pyqtSignal()
    def write(self, text):
        self.printText.emit(str(text))

class UI(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        ...
        self.textedit = QTextEdit(self)
        self.textedit.setGeometry(400,20,220,300)
        self.c = Communicate()
        self.c.printText.connect(self.textedit.insertPlainText)
        sys.stdout = self.c


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ...
```

When I ran the code, I got `TypeError: Communicate.printText[] signal has 0 argument(s) but 1 provided`. But when I tried to provide no argument to `self.printText.emit()`, it said that `self.textedit.insertPlainText` needs 1 argument. Did I miss something? Your answer will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the parameters when defining the signal. Also, you should probably provide a dummy `flush` method, to avoid attribute errors:

```
class Communicate(QObject):
    printText = pyqtSignal(str)

    def write(self, text):
        self.printText.emit(text)

    def flush(self):
        pass
```